# How to use grid in VS2010 MVC3 to add and edit data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, grid

I'm using Microsoft VS 2010 C#, MVC3.
I have Calsserooms and Students with many to many relation ship, so I add an intermediat table called Classroom_Students.
When adding students to a classroom, I use a combo box in my view filled with all students names, I choose one by one in every submit

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddStudentToClassroom", "Calssrooms", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.LabelFor(c=>c.Students, "Choose a Student")

            <select name = "StudentID">
                @foreach (var it in Model.Students)
                {
                    <option value="@it.ID">@it.StudentName </option>
                }    
            </select>

            <input type="submit" value= "Add" />
}
```

My question is:
How can I use gride, instead of this combo, to select many students, select all or deselect all to add???
I'll appreciate any help.

This is the code in my controller.
For page first call, I fill combobox as following:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult AddStudentToClassroom(int id)   //id of calssroom
{
    using (ExaminationEntities en = new ExaminationEntities())
    {
        ClassroomDetails ClsromView = new ClassroomDetails ();     // these are for 
        ClsromView.Classroom = en.Classroom.Single(c => c.ID == id);// loading calssroom information and to
            ClsromView.Students = en.Students.ToList();         // fill students list for the combobox
            return View(ClsromView);
        }
    }
```

When submiting the form, view, and click the add button, it calls the following overloaded add function for saving data:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult AddStudentToClassroom(AddStudToCals ClasStud)   //ClasStud is the submited data from the view
{
     using (ExaminationEntities en = new ExaminationEntities())
     {
         ClassroomDetails ClsromView = new ClassroomDetails();          // these are for 
         ClsromView.Calssroom = en.Calssroom.Single(c => c.ID == ClasStud.ClassroomID); // loading calssroom information and to
         ClsromView.Students = en.Student.ToList();                     // fill students list for the combobox

          using (ExaminationEntities exn = new ExaminationEntities())
          {
              Calssroom_Student To_DB_ClasStud = new Calssroom_Student ();      //To_DB_ClasStud object to get the submited values and to save it in the DB
              To_DB_ClasStud.CalssroomID = ClasStud.CalssroomID;
              To_DB_ClasStud.StudentID = ClasStud.StdentID;
              en.AddToClassroom_Student(To_DB_ClasStud);
              en.SaveChanges();
           }
                return View(ClsromView);             
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the option that requires the least changes to your markup is to add the `multiple` property to your `select`. Then, change the action method to accept a `params int[] ids`, iterate through them, and you should be good-to-go. At worst, you might have to change your parameter to a `string` and do a `Split()` on `,`, but I don't recall that being how the model binder supports multi-selects.

If this doesn't seem to fit your needs, there is an article on the ASP.NET website that explains using a `MultiSelectList` to bind to the `ListBox` helper, here:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I need a grid or something similar. I need some thing like my Inbox (select some rows, deselect, select all, deselect all)

Comment: @Dr.MAF If you want something that's plug-and-play, might want to check out Kendo UI: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/index.html (commercial) or jqGrid: http://mvcjquerycontrols.codeplex.com/ (includes other helpers; open-source)